# jQuery chaining error in syntax - Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a flash effect that when run I would like to display a hidden div.  This is what I have so far...

```js
function flash(e) {
        $('.flash')
        .show()  //show the hidden div
        .animate({opacity: 0.5}, 300)
        .(".mydiv").fadeToggle('fast') 
        .fadeOut(300)
       .css({'opacity': 1});
    }
    
    flash();
```

```css
.mydiv {
  display:none;
}
.flash {
  background:green;
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
    My Div
</div>

<div class="flash"></div>
```

If I take out the line that shows the hidden div then it works correctly, is there a different way to chain this so that the div gets displayed right before the fadeout?

Comment: Well the `.(".mydiv")` is the problem; it's not clear what it is that you expect that to do but it's a syntax error.

Comment: After it has animated the opacity I want it to fade the hidden div in but before the fadeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "chaining" system that jQuery implements involves referencing object properties (jQuery methods) on jQuery objects. In this line:

```
    .(".mydiv").fadeToggle('fast')
```

the `.(".mydiv")` therefore doesn't make sense, and it's a JavaScript syntax error.

If you want to fade that "mydiv" element after the animation is complete, you have to use a callback on the `.animate()` method call:

```
    $('.flash')
    .show()  //show the hidden div
    .animate({opacity: 0.5}, 300, function() {
        $(".mydiv").fadeToggle('fast')  
            .fadeOut(300)
            .css({'opacity': 1});
    });
```

Now, it's not clear what you intend by calling both `.fadeToggle()` *and* `.fadeOut()`. All of the animation routines *start* immediately when you call the method but they don't *finish* immediately, and the next method call in the chain doesn't wait for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function flash(e) {
  $('.flash')
    .show()  //show the hidden div
    .animate({opacity: 0.5}, 300)
    .prev(".mydiv").fadeToggle('fast') 
    .fadeOut(300)
    .css({'opacity': 1});
}

flash();
```

```css
.mydiv {
  display:none;
}
.flash {
  background:green;
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
    My Div
</div>

<div class="flash"></div>
```

I've used `jQuery prev` method to get the `.myDiv` element.

Hope this will help you.